# Problem with Regular Expression (for preg_split)

Tags: php, regex

The person who designed this database decided to make a multi-value column for "subjects" with each value written like an ordered list, i.e. "1. [subject] 2. [another subject] 3. [a third subject]" etc. I want to make an array of every subject used, so I need to split these values into distinct subjects.

```
$subjects = preg_split("[0-9]+\.\s", $subject);
```

When I run this, I get a **Warning:** preg_split() [function.preg-split]: Unknown modifier '+'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Delimiters? surround the regex with /'s

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You forgot the delimiters:

```
$subjects = preg_split("/[0-9]+\.\s/", $subject);
```

Also, slap that guy. Hard.

Comment: Thank you everyone! My mistakes are always silly like this. And I would consider physical violence, but it was probably an intern that left years ago.

Comment: +1 also for slapping. I hate when people set up columns like this. Way to completely fail at basic relational database design.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [pattern delimeters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) so php thinks `[` `]` are it.

Use e.g.

`$subjects = preg_split("~[0-9]+\.s~", $subject);`

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, PCREs need [**delimiters**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The most common one used is `/`, but you can also use another character:

```
preg_split('/[0-9]+\.\s/', $subject);
//          ^          ^
```

You get this warning because PHP treats `[]` as delimiters.

This will give you an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => [subject] 
    [2] => [another subject] 
    [3] => [a third subject]
)
```

so you'd have to remove the first item ( `unset($subjects[0])` ).

---

Depending on the possible inputs, using `preg_match_all` might be better:

```
$str = "1. [subject] 2. [another subject] 3. [a third subject]";

preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', $str, $matches); 

$subjects = $matches[1];
// or $subject = $matches[0]; if you want to include the brackets.
```

where `$matches` is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [subject]
            [1] => [another subject]
            [2] => [a third subject]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => subject
            [1] => another subject
            [2] => a third subject
        )

)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "PHP regular expressions" because the [POSIX](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php) family of functions don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your regex with **delimiters** in order to avoid this error:

```
/[0-9]+\.\s/
```